# Worklight 6.2 - cannot get my menuOptions

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

Based on the [document](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_setting_page.html?lang=en), I am supposed to get my phone Worklight Settings page. But on my Android, I am not able to see this page.

I am use the following

Can someone please advise? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your Android OS version?

If you are running Android API level 11 or above (= Android 3.x and above), most chances are that you will not be able to see the Android Options Menu (where you would've found the button to invoke Worklight Settings from in Android).

This is due to Android no longer supporting Options Menu starting the above mentioned API level.
It was replaced with the Action Bar. However, Worklight does not support the Action Bar so you cannot invoke it...

Bottom line - not available based on the above criteria.
Also note the following output in LogCat:

> 08-21 15:13:01.030: W/NONE(1919): Note that if your application
>   targets Android 3.0 (API level 11) or higher, WL.OptionsMenu might
>   have no effect, depending on the device.

Comment: I am on API Level 19 @ Android V4.4.2 running on Android Emulator, and  Sony xPreria Z.

What is the alternative? I want to be able to change my Worklight Server URL.

Comment: There is no good and officially supported way to do this in 6.2; do you understand that using Worklight Settings is a Development feature and not for production? What is your use case?